# Unwind Segue Hides Tab Bar

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I have the following layout :

1. Tab Bar Controller
2. Nav Controller
3. View Controller 1
4. View Controller 2

I am currently trying to unwind segue from View Controller 2 to View Controller 1. The segue works however the tab bar disappears. Is there any way where I can force the tab bar to remain without removing the navigation controller. I have already tried the follow:

1. setting the tabBar.isHidden property to false
2. unchecking the hide bottom bar on push

Any other ideas? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I right understand you have storyboard like this:

[image]

I don't want to be superficial, but you don't need unwindsegue. If is not like this, post your storyboard to give you the right solution.

Comment: This is correct. Turns out that I had originally embedded the second view controller in a separate nav controller and inserted a bar button item. When I deleted the nav controller and set up the situation like in the image above, the bar button saved so the automatic back button never appeared.