# Swift 3 – Tab Bar Hidden on Segue

Tags: swift3, segue, hidden, tabbar

Here is my [setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtAc9.png) (click 'setup' to see picture):

### The Problem

When I segue from Blue back to Green, I lose my tab bar and I can't get to Red. I think this is because the segue that I used covered the entire screen and hid the Tab Bar. What segue should I be using? Why doesn't seguing back show the Tab Bar again?

Note that I want to use a button to switch between `Green/Blue` (so far, only the `Show Detail` segue works) but I want to use the Tab Bar to switch between `Red/Green`.
I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47957054/unwind-segue-hides-tab-bar) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427102/hide-show-tab-bar-when-push-back-swift/35427833) but neither worked for me.

Thanks in advance,

J. Shaw

Comment: Please include the relevant code within your question, if you have questions please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There is no code yet. I just want to go from the BlueViewController to the GreenViewController without losing the Tab Bar @StefanCrain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear on how you removed the tab bar from your Blue View Controller, but the way I'm describing below removes it and it will remain on the Green View Controller when you use the back button.  The result is you'll be able to move Red VC via the Tab Bar.

1. Create a new Cocoa Touch Class File... File -> New File.  I named it GreenVC and make sure you select UIViewController in the Sub Class Of dropdown.
2. Replace the contents of GreenVC with the following code:

import UIKit

```
class GreenVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! UIViewController
        destinationVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    }
}
```

3. Click on the yellow circle at the top of the Green View Controller in the Storyboard.
4. Go to identity inspector and select GreenVC from the Class drop down under Custom Class like so:

[image]

5. You are done!

The Storyboard:

[image]